# DeviceReduceModule throws an OverflowException

Tags: aleagpu

```
let absoluteSumModule = (new DeviceReduceModule<float32>(GPUModuleTarget.Worker(worker), fun a b -> a+b)).Create(128000)
```

I've tried various maxNumItems settings but no mater what it throws the same exception. Unlike last time I have no idea what the error could even possibly be so I've included the whole dump here.

```
Failure
  (Description "$f0(sm52,64)",
   Exception
     System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a UInt16.
   at Alea.CUDA.UsageByInstanceUtil.f@1-46(Object clrModuleInstance, IRModuleBuildingContext ctx, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
   at Alea.CUDA.UsageByInstanceUtil.cudafy@104.Invoke(IRModuleBuildingContext ctx)
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$Compilation.compile@490[T](Template`1 template, FSharpOption`1 bitcodeCache, IRModuleBuildingContext ctx, Unit unitVar0)
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$Compilation.compile@515-7[T](Template`1 template, FSharpOption`1 bitcodeCache, IRModuleBuildingContext ctx, Unit unitVar0),
   System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a UInt16.
   at Alea.CUDA.UsageByInstanceUtil.f@1-46(Object clrModuleInstance, IRModuleBuildingContext ctx, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
   at Alea.CUDA.UsageByInstanceUtil.cudafy@104.Invoke(IRModuleBuildingContext ctx)
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$Compilation.compile@490[T](Template`1 template, FSharpOption`1 bitcodeCache, IRModuleBuildingContext ctx, Unit unitVar0)
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$Compilation.compile@515-7[T](Template`1 template, FSharpOption`1 bitcodeCache, IRModuleBuildingContext ctx, Unit unitVar0))
System.Exception: Compiling failed.
   at Alea.CUDA.Worker.LoadProgram[T](Template`1 template, CompileOptions options)
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$UsageByInstance.-ctor@271-215.Invoke(Unit _arg1)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at <StartupCode$Alea-CUDA>.$UsageByInstance.-ctor@77-214.Invoke(Unit _arg1)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at Alea.CUDA.Unbound.DeviceReduceModule`1.Create(Int32 maxNumItems)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002.main@() in C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Load MNIST\Load MNIST\utils.fsx:line 28
Stopped due to error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I checked that, looks like it is a bug. Will have to check this. It works if you code it in normal F# file, but doesn't work in F# interactive.

In the mean time, in F#, we encourge you to use quotations for the operator, so you can try this:

```
> let worker = Worker.Default;;

val worker : Worker = [0|5.2|GeForce GTX 970|7]

> let m = new DeviceReduceModule<float32>(GPUModuleTarget.Worker(worker), <@ (+) @>);;
Binding session to 'C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\Inbox\Library3\packages\Alea.CUDA.IL.2.1.2.3274\lib\net40\Alea.CUDA.IL.dll'...

val m : DeviceReduceModule<float32>

> m.GPUForceLoad();;
Binding session to 'C:\Users\Xiang\Documents\Inbox\Library3\packages\Alea.CUDA.2.1.2.3274\lib\net40\Alea.CUDA.dll'...
val it : unit = ()
> let x = m.Create(128000);;

val x : DeviceReduce<float32>

>
```

So, instead of using `fun a b -> a + b` you can try `<@ fun a b -> a + b @>`, or simply `<@ (+) @>`.

Comment: Thank you for being so patient in answering all my questions.